# FB.Canvas.setSize() "invalid argument" error in all.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

For some strange reason calling FB.Canvas.setSize(100) for example, console.log() shows following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid argument --- all.js:39
```

Debugging FB:

```
Object {__globalCallbacks: Object, api: function, getLoginStatus: function, getAuthResponse: function, getAccessToken: function…} --- VM2573 main.js:58
```

Debugging FB.Canvas:

```
Object {setSize: function, setAutoGrow: function, getPageInfo: function, scrollTo: function, setDoneLoading: function…} --- VM2681 main.js:58
```

So the Object seems OK. (also the function is defined as you can see)
There are no other JS errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [FB.Canvas.setSize documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/):

This call has a **single required object** with the name params. The object must have the following properties set on it:

- **width** integer

  - Desired width. Max is app width.
  - Optional
  - Default: frame width
- **height** integer

  - Desired height.
  - Optional
  - Default: frame height

So the correct way to call it is:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });
```

Each property is optional so you can also call it like this:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 480 });

FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640 });

FB.Canvas.setSize();
```

Also remember:

> When determining the Canvas Height automatically the height it can
>   only be increased, not decreased.